# How to check if a file exists in a specific folder of an android device

Tags: android, python, testing, directory, audio-recording

I am writing an **automation test** using **python**, where an **android** app records an audio and stores it in a **specific directory** within the **internal storage** (sdcard0) of the android device.

I need to check whether the recording (recordingX.mp3) actually exists with the same name within the specific directory or not..  If YES, the latest file should be given a new name.

Can someone suggest me how to write a **python test** for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
File file = new File(path);
if(file.exists())
{
  Toast.makeText(this,"file present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
  Toast.makeText(this,"file not present", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question.. I need python code to test. what you suggested was java i guess..

Comment: Can you please suggest solution for the above problem ?? or can you  tag someone who is good at python..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lines:

```
        String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "YourFileName";

        File newFile = new File(path);
        if (newFile.exists()) {
            oldfile.renameTo("newName");
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please suggest solution for the above problem ?? or can you tag someone who is good at python..